# How to update multiple rows in one column in one query SQL

Tags: sql

I have a table with the following customer order data. I am trying to clean up one column that shows the state the customer is in. This column has a mix of full state names and their abbreviations and I want to just have the abbreviations. Below is the gist of what I came up with but I'm not sure what's wrong. I have to end up doing this for basically every state.

```
UPDATE customer_orders 
SET state = CASE 
   WHEN 'Colorado' THEN 'CO'
   WHEN 'Wisconsin' THEN 'WI'
END 
WHERE state IN ('Colorado', 'Wisconsin');
```

Comment: Your code is fine.

Comment: If the table is huge, it could be a good idea to instead do 50 updates, i.e. take one state per UPDATE. (Especially if it's a live system.)

Comment: If you have permissions or support of database-administrator, you could also create a translation-table (e.g. `states` with columns `name` to `abbreviation`) and use that in a lookup like `UPDATE customer_orders SET state = (SELECT abbreviation FROM states WHERE name = state)` .. but also considering not-covered state-names.

Answer (score 2):

You could join onto a `VALUES` table constructor, with state names and codes.

Like this:

```sql
UPDATE c
SET state = s.code
FROM customer_orders AS c
JOIN (VALUES
    ('CO','Colorado),
    ('WI','Wisconsin'),
    -- .....etc
) AS s(code,name) ON s.name = c.state;
```

Comment: Nice answer, but product specific - to a question with no dbms specified. Which dbms is this for?

Comment: @jarlh SQL Server, but it's also available withs slight differences on Postgres, DB2, SQLite and MariaDB. I think MySQL and Oracle you can also do this with a derived table with `UNION ALL`

Answer (score 1):

You would just build a CASE statement that covers all states.

```
UPDATE customer_orders SET state =
   CASE WHEN state = 'Colorado' THEN 'CO'
        WHEN state = 'Wisconsin' THEN 'WI'
        ....
        ELSE state
   END;
```

You technically don't have to filter by a where statement unless you have other junk data in the state column that you don't want to touch.

Comment: To filter might keep the transaction size down, and also reduce the risk of transaction conflict.

Answer (score 0):

`CASE WHEN` Statement required boolean condition after `WHEN`. If you don't it, you get this error:

> An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a
> condition is expected, near 'THEN'.

Therefore you must compare state in `when` condition like as below:

```
UPDATE customer_orders 
SET state = CASE 
   WHEN state = 'Colorado' THEN 'CO'
   WHEN state = 'Wisconsin' THEN 'WI'
END 
WHERE state IN ('Colorado', 'Wisconsin');
```

For more information about usage `CASE` statement in `UPDATE`, you can visit this link: [Usage CASE statement in UPDATE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#d-using-case-in-an-update-statement)

Comment: "_CASE expression_"

Comment: @jarlh thanks for comment, but it is called "CASE statement" in w3school https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_case.asp

Comment: Too bad, don't listen to them.